# Refinery Save Page not Working Right

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm using Refinery in one of my projects, but I'm running into a page update issue. When I try to make changes to a page, and then click "Save", viewing the page still shows the old content. If I go back to edit the page, I see the new content.

I've learned that going to the public folder and then deleting the page that I changed fixes my issue, and thus shows the changes, but doing that is too involved for the client. Is this a refinery configuration issue? I've noticed that only one of the three refinery apps we have does this.

Has anyone ran into this before, and how did you fix it if you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. For whatever reason, Refinery was creating static HTML pages as a cache, and when they are removed, it regenerates them with new content as soon as the page is hit.

All I did to solve it was start a cron job that told the site to find all the files that ended in ".html" and remove them. That solved our problem.